# ImageView contentMode to scale images properly?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm drawing a bunch of UIImageView  (100x100) as menu items. Each has its own image, some are larger than 100x100, some smaller. By default, the imageViews with larger images are being scaled down in ratio to fit the 100x100 box nicely.

However, images smaller than 100x100 are being scaled up, which makes them really blurry. I'd like it so the smaller images simply remain the size they naturally are. Otherwise I'm happy with the way large images are scaling, just not the smaller images.

I haven't been able to achieve anything by switching to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, or `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`.

Does anyone have ideas or hacks on how I could achieve this? I could use an if statement to check the image's dimensions and sent their contentMode (Center?), but that seems a bit hackish since I'm drawing each item from an `NSDictionary` with a `for in` loop. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can just check the image dimensions first before setting your frame, something like:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageName:@"myimage.png"]];
[imageView sizeToFit];

CGRect newFrame = imageView.frame;
if (newFrame.size.width > 100) newFrame.size.width = 100;
imageView.frame = newFrame;
```

You'll need some extra logic to do similar things for the height.  Is this what you mean?